# How can stop to jump next view controller? (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I am using segue to send data from one `viewController` to `destinationViewController`. I set button and use push segue to connects to next view controller. In the first view, I set a boolean to check the images is or not empty. If there is any empty, it will pop up alert to remind users. If success, it will send the images to next view controller.

Although I can transmit the images and pop up the alert, it also jump to next view controller if there is any empty. Moreover, the alert is popped after jumping to next view controller, not in the first view controller

Now, here is the code

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if Jumpsuit.isHidden == false && self.Hair.image != nil && self.Jumpsuit.image != nil && self.Shoes.image != nil {

        let DestViewController : ChooseBGViewController = segue.destination as! ChooseBGViewController

        DestViewController.imgHair = Hair.image
        DestViewController.imgJumpsuit = Jumpsuit.image
        DestViewController.imgShoes = Shoes.image
        DestViewController.dressingtype = 1
    } else if Jumpsuit.isHidden == false && self.Hair.image == nil || self.Jumpsuit.image == nil || self.Shoes.image == nil {
        let alert = UIAlertView()
        alert.title = "No Image"
        alert.message = "Please check again"
        alert.addButton(withTitle: "OK")
        alert.show()

    }
}
```

How can I stop jumping to next view controller and pop up the alert in first view controller. Please help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621502-shouldperformsegue) for that and return `Bool` value according your condtion.

```
override func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    if Jumpsuit.isHidden == false && self.Hair.image == nil || self.Jumpsuit.image == nil || self.Shoes.image == nil {
         //Show UIAlertController instead of UIAlertView it is deprecated
         return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: Now, i can pop up in first view controller, but I can't send the images to next view controller. Where should I add the code?

Comment: I did it. Thankyou very much!

Comment: @HappyChan Welcome mate :)

Answer (score 0):

When the user tapped the button you would use the `IBAction` that will first check what you need (the image..) and then you could use 2 approaches:

1. You can now use [performSegue](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621413-performseguewithidentifier) which will trigger the known prepareForSegue and use the segue you created
2. You can use the [instantiateViewController(withIdentifier](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uistoryboard/1616214-instantiateviewcontroller): approach as follows (and don't forget to disconnect the segue):

   ```
   let nextVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YourViewControllerID")
   self.present(nextVC!, animated: true, completion: nil)
   ```

   or if you have navigation controller:

   ```
   self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextVC!, animated: true)
   ```